# windows forms not implemented exception in Listbox_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I may have inadvertently clicked on the listbox object when in Forms Designer View and created the following methods, which I did not need. Now I don't know how to undo this. When I remove the method Visual Studio is not happy, and if I don't I get an exception error when I click an object in the listbox. I do not know why I get this error and how to fix it. It may also be due to some other error, which I need to fix

```
private void PrizesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void tournamentPlayersListbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I have tried to look up the answer.

Comment: Delete the two methods, then delete their references from the respective controls events

Comment: @maccettura-that must be a new record. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can be solved by going to the listbox's property(right click on your listbox control and then select property). In property window you can find events. By clicking the event you will get all the events that the listbox have. Just remove the event name from the SelectedIndexChanged event. Rebuild the project and run.

Answer (score 0):

When you will build the project, You will get an error. Double click on that error, it will take you to the code(In the designer) from where the error is coming.

It will be something like -

```
    this.PrizesListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.PrizesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Just remove this line, and you are done.